# A way to get relative paths to work using subdomains?

Tags: php, javascript, linux

When accessing a page through a subdomain, all includes and relative paths break (even though the directory structure on the server should allow for the relative path to find it).  What's the best way to have files on multiple subdomains access central resources (without using absolute paths)?

An JavaScript example:

```
m_url : '../code/php/UserAPI.php',

    $.ajax({
        url: someClass.m_url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: paras,
        success: function(ret){someClass.onLoggedIn(ret, callback)}
    });
```

if this UserAPI is called from `subdomain1.example.com` and `subdomain2.example.com` but the php resides on `example.com` how can one make the relative path follow the linux directory structure instead of adding trying to concatenate the subdomain/domain path?

ps. The reason m_url can't be hard coded is because the code has to work on both development and production servers.

Thanks as always!!

Comment: Is there a reason your deployment tools can't specify m_url at build time?

Comment: Whole question is unclear and senseless. Client never requests "concatenated domain path" but it requests an **URI** from some **domain**. Separately. Your problem is awfully unclear. There should be not a single problem if all subdomains being served by one virtual host. Can you be more specific while describing your problem? Bering examples of what you want and what you get.

Comment: :D unclear and senseless?  Three other people seem to have got what I was asking.  The client is requesting `subdomain1.example.com/[m_url]` when called from pages from subdomain1 and `subdomain2.example.com/[m_url]` when called from pages from subdomain2 even though I need it to call `example.com/[m_url]` but not use an absolute path because I want to migrate the code between production and development servers.  Anyway, seems I got the answer to my question.  Let me know *how* you'd like me to clean the question up since I've already brought examples.

Comment: +1 @Elf that's true and another great answer!  I could (and maybe should) handle this at build time.

Comment: You just messing the terms. Path never include domain part. It's URL that includes both domain and path parts. You are talking of urls, not paths. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator#Syntax a path is a thing between last `/` and `?` But whole address is called URL. And here is not such thing like absolute or relative URL. These terms just inapplicable to URLs. Finally to your question: if you want to call another **domain** you ought to request this domain, using fill qualified url. Because paths works within current domain only.

Comment: I am not only one deceived by your question. Both answers below are about paths. While you are talking of domains. I am still not sure what is your problem exactly. And again. A client never concatenate domains. And it never call whole url as is. URL being parsed, It's  domain used to determine server to connect and then an URI being requested from that server. URI begins from the path. Always absolute. Hope this helps you to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `$_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']` to determine the current position based on filesystem and then go relative to that.  However, it would [require some tweaking to the Apache setup](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Perhaps an alternate solution would be to sense via $_SERVER what host you're on (Dev, Prod, etc) and define those paths as needed.  Then, just set your prefix before defining path.  Sure, it requires a few extra lines of code, but it cuts the brain damage in half.  That strategy has been used in many large production environments I've worked in.

Comment: PATH_TRANSLATED won't help with domains

Answer (score 1):

As bpeterson76 answered, `$_SERVER['PATH_TRANSLATED']` and `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']` will you give the raw server path of the script, which you can then adjust depending on your subdomain structure.

These server variables aren't always available, so you could instead use the PHP function `getcwd()` - this will return the directory of the script without the filename. Then adjust as above.

Comment: +1 @edanfalls ... great alternative with getcwd!  Giving it to bpeterson for being the early bird.